# Minify Maven Plugin throwing "JavaScript engine not supported" error

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, minify

How can I configure the [Minify Maven Plugin](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/) plugin to work with Maven 2.2.1 while also using the Google Closure Compiler?

According to [this issue](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin/issues/54), Version 1.7.1 should work with that particular version of Maven, but on minification, it is throwing this warning: "[WARNING] JavaScript engine not supported". The concatenation of the bundles works as expected. I am upgrading from version 1.2.4 to the utilize the the Closure Compiler. I need Closure Compiler as YUI has some unresolved bugs with certain ES2015 syntax. We won't be upgrading to Maven 3 for a while.

workstation details:

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 12:16:01-0700)
Java version: 1.8.0_60
OS name: "mac os x" version: "10.10.4" arch: "x86_64" Family: "mac"
```

My configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>someBundle</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <webappSourceDir>web/src/static${static.asset.basedir}</webappSourceDir>
                    <webappTargetDir>web/target/minify</webappTargetDir>
                    <jsSourceFiles>
                        <param>libs/somelib.js</param>
                        <param>libs/anotherlib.js</param>
                    </jsSourceFiles>
                    <jsFinalFile>bundle.js</jsFinalFile>
                    <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>minify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was pretty obscure so I'll answer it by posting my solution. I was fearful that upgrading to Maven 3 would open up a can of worms, but it didn't. As a matter of fact, it just worked after changing the location of the Maven home directory (in IntelliJ and in the zsh profile - M2_HOME) and the location of our Maven Repository (which was not in the default location). I build with both IntelliJ and by command line so both locations needed to be updated.

New home directory location (installed with Homebrew):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
```

Local Maven repository setting updated in this file:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec/conf/settings.xml
```

Update this value:

```
<localRepository>/path/to/local/maven/repository/</localRepository>
```